# How do you get macOS Sierra (10.12.1) to lock and ask for a password after display sleep?

Tags: security, upgrade, sleep-wake, password, macos

After upgrading to 10.12.1 my Mac no longer locks after display sleep. Before the update, a login prompt always appeared. This is either using:

1. The keyboard (⌘ ⌥ power)
2. Timing out (set for 10min)
3. Closing the clam shell.

Comment: So far two coworkers have had the same issue. One of them didn't notice the issue because he uses a screensaver which still honored his existing locking preferences.

Answer (score 4):

So I figured it out a solution as soon as I could ask.

I toggled the Require Password settings to "Immediately" then back to my previous "5 seconds" and now all seems to be working properly.

[image: Changing required password time.]

This required my password each time but well worth the re-enabled security. You may even be able to just uncheck then recheck the Required box. I can't test this because my issue is fixed.

Comment: Just curious, what app did you use to make the .gif image in your answer?

Comment: [licecap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/)

Comment: My solution fixed the above mentioned issue for two coworkers.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Was curious if there is a way to do this via the command line?

Comment: I had exact the same issue after upgrading to 10.12.1, but i can't change the "Require password xxx after sleep or screen saver begins" option because it is grey. i have typed my password and have access to change all settings except this one. It is so strange.

Comment: I successfully used my solution again after upgrading to macOS Sierra **10.12.3**. But this shouldn't be happening.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for 10.13.3. Use the new command `^⌘Q`

Comment: @cottsak That should probably be an answer of itself.  As an aside, this is a serious bug - I'm surprised I can't find any other reference for this on the web, anyone spotted anything relevant?

Comment: That's prob because they only changed it very recently.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your settings under System Preference-General.
There's a setting there for requiring password after sleep or after screen saver begins, might have changed?
Hope it'll work for you.